# C# winform add panel dock setting

Tags: c#, winforms, dock

I need to add multiple panel into main panel, when I added second panel it will move on top the first added panel. please refer the image if you can't get what i means.

the question is, how can I add the following panel below the panel I just add?

```
public override DockStyle Dock { get; set; }
private void resultlabel()
    {

       Panel panel1 = new Panel();
       panel1.Height = 50;
       panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
       panel1.AutoSize = false;
       panel1.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly;
       panel1.AllowDrop = false;
       panel1.CausesValidation = true;
       if((totalitem % 2) == 0)
        {
          panel1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        else
        {
          panel1.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        }
       Label label1 = new Label();
       label1.Text = count.ToString();
       panel1.Controls.Add(label1);
       mainPanel.Controls.Add(panel1);
       count= count+ 1;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I get the result is 4,3,2,1 but what I need is 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your z-order to change the order of docked panels. Your best bet not to change a lot of code would be using:

```
panel1.BringToFront();
```

Or

```
panel1.SendToBack();
```

Depending on the order you want

This needs to be done ***after*** adding it to `mainPanel` (that is, after the `mainPanel.Controls.Add(panel1);` line)

Answer (score 0):

You get the result because of this:

```
panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
```

So each panel you add is added to the top. Can you add the panels in a reverse order? That would be a quick solution, otherwise you could look into TableLayoutPanel or FlowLayoutPanel if that would be a useful approach for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use   `panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;` intead of :  `panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;`

Comment: But that would dock them to the bottom, not to the top, as the OP wants